# Selenium RemoteWebDriver.executeScript() how can I get value out

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, automated-tests

I have a CodeMirror code editor. I'm filling it using ExecuteScript webdriver method with Javascript inside

```
driver.ExecuteScript("editor.setValue('console.log();');");
```

After it I'm getting the value using `editor.getValue()`

`getValue()` returns a string, whereas `ExecuteScript()` returns an object. And I need the string value from `getValue()` for comparing. How can I have this value out?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as easy as pie : I needed to use 'return'

```
var text = driver.ExecuteScript("var r = editor.getValue(); return r;");
```